# ¿Como borrar una tabla de access a una determinada fecha?

Tags: ms-access

no sé mucho de VB en access, pero me gustaría saber cómo programar el borrado de los datos de una tabla, o la tabla completa cuando se cumpla una condición de fecha. Es decir, cuando la fecha del sistema (del computador o servidor) sea mayor o igual a ejemplo 28-02-2021, la tabla o sus datos sean borrados.

If date()>= 28/01/2021 then

DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table"

End if

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Las preguntas del estilo necesito hacer tal o cual cosa, sin mostrar lo que se ha intentado **no son bien recibidas por la comunidad** Por favor entra a [edit] e incluye lo que has tratado de hacer. Si aún no has intentado nada, con seguridad tu pregunta será cerrada sin más atención.

Comment: Hola. No puedes usar las respuestas para comentar cosas. Por favor, lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Ttendrías que ponerlo en un objeto que se cargue al abrir la base. Por ejemplo, yo tengo una base que al abrirla carga un formulario por defecto, y en el código de ese formulario, en el evento `Al cargar` tengo metido un código que vacía una tabla.

Aquí puedes ver cómo elegir un formulario que se cargue al abrir una base:

> **[Establecer el formulario predeterminado que aparece al abrir una base de datos de
> Access](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/establecer-el-formulario-predeterminado-que-aparece-al-abrir-una-base-de-datos-de-access-94961011-392f-4c3b-8dbc-e5d5adbff1df)**

Luego, en ese formulario en el evento `Al cargar`, para **vaciar una tabla** puedes usar este código.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
If Date >= CDate("28/01/2021") Then 'elige fecha
    Dim MiSQL As String
    MiSQL = "DELETE * FROM Tabla1"
    
    With Application.DoCmd
    .SetWarnings False 'DESACTIVAMOS CONFIRMACIÓN
    .RunSQL MiSQL
    .SetWarnings True 'REACTIVAMOS CONFIRMACIÓN
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Si lo que quieres es **borrar el objeto de la base de datos** entonces sí sería tu código.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
If Date >= CDate("28/01/2021") Then 'elige fecha
    With Application.DoCmd
    .SetWarnings False 'DESACTIVAMOS CONFIRMACIÓN
    .DeleteObject acTable, "Tabla1"
    .SetWarnings True 'REACTIVAMOS CONFIRMACIÓN
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Ojo, no es lo mismo vaciar una tabla (eliminar los registros existentes, primer código) que eliminar la propia tabla en sí (segundo código, la tabla deja de existir).

Elige bien la opción que necesitas.